# How to handle strings with variables when translating an HTML website?

Tags: javascript, json, html, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary to translate a website. The problem is I can't find a way to catch strings with variables in it! For example:

```
<div ... lang="fr">Something 52 something else</div>
```

where 52 is a variable and could be any number. What I was hoping for is something like this:

> "Something * something else":"blabla * blablabla bla"

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: do you mean: `div[lang=fr]` ?

Comment: I'm not using php, only html and js!

Comment: You can use http://i18next.com/ to translate you text using JS. It does manage variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are always free to implement that yourself:

```
function frmtStr() {
  var argCnt, out;

  argCnt = arguments.length;
  if (argCnt < 1) {
    return ""
  }
  out = arguments[0]; // your localized string.

  if (argCnt < 2) {
    return out
  }
  for(var i = 1; i < argCnt; i++) {
    // replace '*' with the arguments
    out = out.replace(/\*/, arguments[i]);
  }
  return out; 
}

frmtStr('foo *', 'bar'); // foo bar
frmtStr('foo * *', 'bar', 'lorem'); // foo bar lorem
frmtStr('* bar * * ', 'foo', 'lorem', 'ipsum'); // foo bar lorem ipsum
```

This is not perfect but it should give you an idea. I'd bet there are tons of libraries that offer this feature.

Comment: Unordered placeholders is sometimes not sufficient, as languages can change the order of parameters. Add `$1, $2` or similar, so the ordering can be changed.

Comment: my dictionary is JSON! I dont know think I can call functions in there!

Comment: You need update your html with the values from the dictionary. Something like this should do it. `document.getElementById(<theId>).innerHTML=frmtStr(<DictionaryStringForThatId>, <arguments ...>)`